# Threads in for loops

Tags: c, for-loop, pthreads

I'm writing a program in C to calculate the access time to certain websites. The sitenames are stored in each element of urls array. If I take out the for (y = 0; y < iterations; y++) loop, then everything runs fine. But if if I keep it. urls[0], the first website, gets messed up after the second for loop completely finishes and increments y

What's causing this?

```
char *urls[50]; char str1[20];

void *wget(void *argument)
{
  int threadid;
  threadid = *((int *)argument);
  strcpy(str1, "wget -q --spider ");
  strcat(str1, urls[threadid]);
  system(str1);
}


for (y = 0; y < iterations; y++)
{
  for (j = 0; j < numthreads; j++)
  {
        thread_args[j] = j;

        clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &bgn);
        rc = pthread_create(&threads[j], NULL, wget, (void *) &thread_args[j]);
        rc = pthread_join(threads[j], NULL);
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &nd);
        times[j] = timediff(bgn,nd);
  }
}
```

Comment: why are you creating a thread and then joining it right away? That is a waste and could slow down your times.

Comment: Not just a waste, it makes threads totally pointless. You might as well replace `pthread_create` and `pthread_join` with a simple call to `wget(&thread_args[j]);`

Comment: From a throughput standpoint it would make more sense to do the creates in one loop and do the joins in a second loop. Then again, you don't need threads to spawn a bunch of child processes in parallel--`fork()`/`exec()` in a loop then `wait()` for them to exit.

Answer (score 5):

Some possibilities...

`str1` appears to be shared among all the threads.  That's a recipe for trouble right there.

`str1` is only 20 chars long.  Hard to believe the whole `wget` command line including the URL will be less than 20 chars.  So you're writing off the end of `str1`.

Consider making `str1` a local variable in `wget()`, and either make it a char array big enough to handle the largest possible `wget` command line you might have, or dynamically allocate it and free it within `wget()` with a size based on the length of the constant part of the command line and the current URL.

Comment: ^ For the first one, yes but I called a pthread_join() to wait for each thread to finish so  there wouldn't be a resource conflict with str1, right?

Answer (score 3):

My bet is that one of the strings in `urls` + the wget string are longer than 20 bytes and are overwriting that data.  Make `str1` larger, and move it into your wget function (multiple threads should not be writing to one shared resource without locking).

Comment: Thanks guys, str1 was the problem. I changed it to str1[200] and it didn't run out of room!